# C# - How can I create 2 separate button arrays with different controls without them causing problems with the other?

Tags: c#, button, grid

I am currently trying to develop a form of battleships on c# windows form. 
Here is the code I am trying to use.. the trouble I have been having is how to create a second set of buttons (another 10x10) behind the other, with two sets of controls so I can switch between the two.

I have everything like AI and automated setups, I just need to have 2 button controls. I hope someone can help me out with this! Many thanks!

```
private List<List<Button>> grid = new List<List<Button>>();

public UserForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    byte numRows = 10;
    byte numCols = 10;
    for (byte i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
    {
        grid.Add(ButtonRowCreator(numCols, 25, (i+1) * 50));
    }
}

public List<Button> ButtonRowCreator(byte numOfBtnsNeeded, int x, int y)
{
    List<Button> btns = new List<Button>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfBtnsNeeded; i++)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        btn.Location = new Point(x + (i * btn.Width), y);
        btns.Add(btn);
        btn.Font = new Font("Georiga", 10);
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    }
    return btns;
}


void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;

    int curRow = -1, curCol = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < grid.Count; i++)
    {
        int index = grid[i].IndexOf(btn);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            curRow = i;
            curCol = index;
            Console.WriteLine("curRow = " + curRow.ToString() + ", curCol = " + curCol.ToString());
        }
    }

    // ... now you can use "curRow", "curCol" and "grid" to do something ...
    foreach (List<Button> row in grid)
    {
        foreach (Button col in row)
        {
            col.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
        }
    }

    if (board[curRow, curCol] == 1)
    {
        if (btn.Text == "Hit")
        {
        }
        else
        {
        btn.Text = "Hit";
        btn.BackColor = Color.Red;
        hit++;
        }
        if (hit == 17)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Congratulations, You Sunk Their Battleships!");
            MessageBox.Show("Thanks For Playing!");
            MessageBox.Show("Goodbye!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        btn.Text = "Miss!";
        btn.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }
```

Comment: What kind of problems are you having? Is it just creating a 2nd set of buttons or is there more?

Comment: Just a second set of buttons, every time I have tried, it has caused issues as i haven't been able to figure out how to separate a different set of controls.

To put it simply, I just want to control it as if they were two separate projects.

Comment: What did you try and what issues did it cause? You should include these in the question.

Comment: I tried doubling up the code, which simply just caused a lot of name issues. I also tried transferring it to a class and changing it to be able to call upon it, that way I could call from separate classes, however that failed due to the change in the syntax.

The code I tried was either unreachable or it contradicted with the names of the first set of buttons

There weren't too many issues, I kept trying random things and doing some research, but I haven't found anything that has helped me yet.

The importance is that I want to control them both, so I can change visibility to switch between.

Comment: I'm still not clear what you are trying to achieve? 2 UserForms or 1 UserForm with two 10x10 buttons grid? How should the grids be positioned? Maybe you should draw a diagram.

Comment: I want the grids, one under the other. All on one form. One grid of buttons would be for the user to interact with, the other would be a display for the AI to interact with. 

Both grids would be positioned in the same place (10 x 10), on a single form. Different controls for each set of 10x10 to change visibility in order to switch between users input and AI display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after?

It looks like a lot of your code is used to figure out what button is clicked on. This information can be stored on the button object itself in the Tag property and greatly simplifies the code.

```
private Button[,] _grid1;
private Button[,] _grid2;

public UserForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _grid1 = new Button[10, 10];
    _grid2 = new Button[10, 10];

    CreateGrid(_grid1, 10, 10, 25, 0, 20, true);
    CreateGrid(_grid2, 10, 10, 25, 250, 20, false);
}

public void CreateGrid(Button[,] grid, int numOfRows, int numOfCols, int offsetX, int offsetY, int buttonSize, bool enabled)
{
    for (byte i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++)
    {
        for (byte j = 0; j < numOfCols; j++)
        {
            grid[i,j] = ButtonCreator(i, j, offsetX, offsetY, buttonSize, enabled);
        }
    }
}

public Button ButtonCreator(int row, int col, int x, int y, int buttonSize, bool enabled)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Size = new Size(buttonSize, buttonSize);
    btn.Location = new Point(x + (col * buttonSize), y + (row * buttonSize));
    btn.Font = new Font("Georiga", 10);
    this.Controls.Add(btn);
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    btn.Tag = row + "," + col;
    btn.Enabled = enabled;
    return btn;
}

void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    string[] coord = btn.Tag.ToString().Split(',');

    int curRow = Convert.ToInt32(coord[0]);
    int curCol = Convert.ToInt32(coord[1]);

    Console.WriteLine(curRow = " + curRow + ", curCol = " + curCol);

    // ... now you can use "curRow", "curCol" to do something ...
    _grid1[curRow, curCol].BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Kind of. I appreciate the effort. It was quite close to what I wanted. However I am trying to stress that I want to be able to control the two grids separately in order to have the computer control one and the user control the other. 

I imagine there is some way to adapt it so i can do that, but I can't figure that out. When I tested the code you have suggested to me, it worked, however both sets of buttons were wired to the same controls and I could figure how to control one set differently.

Comment: What do you mean by "control one set differently"? You can control each grid (_grid1, _grid2) to do what you want. Do you mean you don't want user to be able to click on second grid?

Comment: Exactly that, the second grid I want the AI to interact with but not the user.

Comment: how does AI "interact" with grid?

Comment: The AI would literally just be whatever I code for the computer to do, once the user has taken their turn. So by interact, I simply mean for the second grid to be unusable by the user, but still intractable by the coding (computer/AI) itself.

Comment: so basically you want grid1 to be clickable by user and grid2 to be disabled?

Comment: Yes, that's about it :)

Comment: Updated to enable grid1 and disable grid2.

Comment: That's brilliant, Thank you!! Had to tweak it a little bit because of slight syntax errors but it's great! :) I appreciate it :)